# Recreating NSApplication.Main in monomac

Tags: monomac, nsapplication

I'm trying to recreate nsapplication.main in my app. I want to make my app do a number of things my way rather than automatically doing things I don't want. I guess I'm a code control freak. Sadly, NSEvent E is always null, what am I missing? Thanks for any help :D

```
NSApplication.Init ();
using (var p = new NSAutoreleasePool ()) {
NSApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate = new AppDelegate ();
NSApplication.SharedApplication.FinishLaunching();
NSEvent E
do{
        E=NSApplication.SharedApplication.NextEvent(NSEventMask.AnyEvent,NSDate.DistantFuture,NSRunLoop.NSDefaultRunLoopMode,true);
NSApplication.SharedApplication.SendEvent(E);
NSApplication.SharedApplication.UpdateWindows();
}while(true);
}
```